# Browser to issue new HTTP request based on response from another HTTP request

Tags: javascript, http, browser

I'm looking to *dynamically* issue a new HTTP request from the client/browser based on response from an earlier HTTP request, in the same page load. Basically, the flow would look something like this:

1. Issue HTTP request to [www.site1.com/fetch](http://www.site1.com/fetch), and parse response to get some string `mydata`.
2. Issue HTTP request to [www.site2.com/lookup?key={mydata}](http://www.site2.com/lookup?key=%7Bmydata%7D), substituting in the data just obtained. This call should be done in the same page load.

This is related to HTTP redirections, but it's done on the client-side with more flexibility, to possibly a different domain.

I think client-side JS is the best way to achieve this (perhaps with some kind of callback), but I'm open to other ideas.

Comment: Why wouldn't this be handled on the server? In what situation would you have "more flexibility" by handling it in the client? (Server-side redirects can point to a different domain.) If you need a conditional redirect that involves the server, do it in one pass: The client points the browser to a specific url, including the data needed to make a decision. The server responds with a redirect based on that data.

Comment: @Ouroborus One scenario: say you're the owner of ouroborus.com, but you don't own site1.com or site2.com.

Comment: If that's the case, then it's also likely the third-party sites haven't opened CORS access or that you need to keep an access token private. In those case, server side transaction is either required or preferred.